# Why does AWS SDK V2 add x-id query param to S3 GetObject Requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

We are currently upgrade our aws sdk in golang from v1 to v2 as their migration guide and mostly everything is working okay except for some S3 Get requests.

As far as I can tell in v1 the logs indicate a path as follows:
"bucket/key"

but in v2 the logs say:
"bucket/key?x-id=GetObject"

We are getting a `NoSuchKey` error even though the file is there. This query param being added is the only difference I can see between the requests made between v1 and v2.

Resources:
https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/

All we have tried is studying the differences between our implementation of the v1 and v2 SDK.

Comment: https://andrewarrow.substack.com/p/installing-go-from-source-to-debug in your ~/gp/pkg/mod/github.com/x find the actual code and add fmt.Println vs trying to read the docs. The code is the docs!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I'm with Andrew on this: the question is basically asking why a third-party library changed some aspect of its behavior between two its major versions. This question is not about programming _in_ Go, and the library is open source, so the answer can be found by studying the code. Also, there's the library issue tracker which should be searched for similar problems.

Comment: I would recommend "a trick": with 99.9% confidence, the code of aws-sdk-go is hosted using Git. Clone the project, find where the new header is being added to requests (use plain search for the "x-id" string), and then use `git blame` (which is supported in any sensible contemporary IDE out of the box, usually called "annotate (file) with Git"), and then, if needed, dig deeper through the history to find the commit which implemeted adding of those IDs to S3 requests. The text of the commit (or the MR/PR which integrated it) shoud be clear on the reasons of this addition.

Comment: One more note. The problem is not necessarily due to "x-id" being added, so you might need to bisect the problem field. For instance, you could patch your local copy of aws-sdk-go (Go modules mechanism provides for overriding any depencency by diverting the location of its source code to a place of your choice) to make it stop adding "x-id" to outgoing requests and see whether that fixes the problem.

Comment: fwiw, the reason for the `x-id` parameter, is because the client generator they use (smithy) falls over the duplicate uri's in the S3 spec. The `x-id` parameter was added to disambiguate those requests that needed disambiguation, but is ignored by the AWS S3 server. Ref. [awslabs issue](https://github.com/awslabs/smithy-rs/issues/1012) and related [smithy issue](https://github.com/smithy-lang/smithy/issues/1030).